# Pandas and matplotlib - plot scatter on line graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm building a trading bot and currently backtesting. I have two pandas DataFrames, one much longer than the other. The longer contains all the dates and all the indexes for x amount of years. The other data frame only contain the dates and indexes of which I bought or sold.

```
Long_frame = {'date':['2020-01-10', '2020-01-11', '2020-01-12', '2020-01-13', '2020-01-14', '2020-01-15'], 'index': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 20]}
Short_frame = {'date':['2020-01-10', '2020-01-11', '2020-01-13', '2020-01-15'], 'index': [2, 4, 8, 20]}
```

When I try to plot this on the same graph the line or scatter of the short list end up really compact in the beginning of the graph. How should I plot this to get a meaningful graph? The optimal graph would be to only have one line, the long one, and plot points on that line where trades occurred.

Thanks!

Comment: What are the x and y axis in your plot? x axis is 2,4,6,8 and y axis is the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dates for your x-axis:

```
Long_frame = {'date':['2020-01-10', '2020-01-11', '2020-01-12', '2020-01-13', '2020-01-14', '2020-01-15'],'index': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 20]}
Short_frame = {'date':['2020-01-10', '2020-01-11', '2020-01-13', '2020-01-15'], 'index': [2, 4, 8, 20]}


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(Long_frame['date'], Long_frame['index'])
plt.plot(Short_frame['date'], Short_frame['index'],'.', markersize=15)
```

The trade date points are located at the date position and both graphs are 'equally distributed'

Comment: Thank you, that looks like what I'm after. I'm guessing it's possible to add an arbitrary amount of dataframes as well?